# How can I get all the events of the buttons on a screen on android in a single method using the kotlin?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, event-handling

I am developing a Calculator for my android learning  using kotlin.
To get the numbers select to users, I need to set the  code below:

```
btn1.setOnClickListener({
            var texto = txtDisplay.text.toString()
            txtDisplay.setText(texto + "1")
        })
        btn2.setOnClickListener({
            var texto = txtDisplay.text.toString()
            txtDisplay.setText(texto + "2")
        })
        btn3.setOnClickListener({
            var texto = txtDisplay.text.toString()
            txtDisplay.setText(texto + "3")
        })
        btn4.setOnClickListener({
            var texto = txtDisplay.text.toString()
            txtDisplay.setText(texto + "4")
        })
        btn5.setOnClickListener({
            var texto = txtDisplay.text.toString()
            txtDisplay.setText(texto + "5")
        })
        btn6.setOnClickListener({
            var texto = txtDisplay.text.toString()
            txtDisplay.setText(texto + "6")
        })
        btn7.setOnClickListener({
            var texto = txtDisplay.text.toString()
            txtDisplay.setText(texto + "7")
        })
        btn8.setOnClickListener({
            var texto = txtDisplay.text.toString()
            txtDisplay.setText(texto + "8")
        })
        btn9.setOnClickListener({
            var texto = txtDisplay.text.toString()
            txtDisplay.setText(texto + "9")
        })
        btn0.setOnClickListener({
            var texto = txtDisplay.text.toString()
            txtDisplay.setText(texto + "0")
        })
```

**Is it possible to centrelize the event handling of all buttons in the single class or method?**

**I would like to a generic solution to reduce the code**

Does anyone know a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is a standard way to handle click events in kotlin.
create Function click listeners in your Class. call this function in onCreate function.

```
 private fun clickListeners()
 {
 btn1.setOnClickListener(this)

 btn2.setOnClickListener(this)
 }
```

extend OnclickListner to your Activity/Fragment.

```
 class A: AppCompatActivity(),View.OnClickListener{
   override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
   // call onclick listener function 
    clickListeners()
 
}
  }
```

then override onClick function and write your onClick Logic.

```
   override fun onClick(v: View?) {

    when (v?.id) {

        R.id.btn1-> {
            txtDisplay.text = txtDisplay.text.toString() +"1"
        }
         R.id.btn2-> {
            txtDisplay.text = txtDisplay.text.toString() +"2"
        }
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

One way would be to create a new class for the click listener:

```
private class MyButtonClickListener(
            private var txtDisplay: TextView, private var s: String
            ) : View.OnClickListener {
        override fun onClick(v: View?) {
            txtDisplay.text = txtDisplay.text.toString() + s
        }
    }
```

then use it as:

```
btn1.setOnClickListener(MyButtonClickListener(txtDisplay, "1"))
btn2.setOnClickListener(MyButtonClickListener(txtDisplay, "2"))
```

and so on..

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest this approach to set onClick listeners.

1.Create onClick listener:

```
private class MyButtonClickListener(
        private var txtDisplay: TextView, private var s: String
        ) : View.OnClickListener {
    override fun onClick(v: View?) {
        txtDisplay.text = txtDisplay.text.toString() + s
    }
}
```

2.And then use iteration over buttons and apply onClick listener to them:

```
val btns = arrayOf(btOne, btTwo, btThree, ...)
for(int i = 1; i <= btns.size; ++i) {
    btns[i].setOnClickListener(MyButtonClickListener(txtDisplay, "$i"))
}
```

Comment: this won't really work, btnOne will have a value of 0, so you should update your array to start with btnZero

Answer (score 0):

create an array of buttons then you can use this loop

```
for (i in 0..9) {
    btn[i].setOnClickListener({
        var texto = txtDisplay.text.toString()
        txtDisplay.text = texto + i.toString()
    })
}
```

Comment: OP is busy learning, they probably don't know how to `create an array of buttons`. might be better if you explained that in your answer perhaps?